# group by and custom sort in telerik radGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, telerik, radgrid

This is how I group my `RadGrid` rows .

```
<GroupByExpressions>
            <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                <SelectFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="TaskStatus" FieldName="TaskStatus" HeaderText="Current Status ">
                    </telerik:GridGroupByField>
                </SelectFields>
                <GroupByFields>
                    <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="TaskStatus" SortOrder="Ascending"></telerik:GridGroupByField>
                </GroupByFields>
            </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
        </GroupByExpressions>
```

It works find and grid data show likes ,

```
     id                   Name                      Detail
==============================================================================
> Current Status : Done
      1                   Name1                     Detail
      2                   Name2                     Detail 
> Current Status : None
      5                   Name3                     Detail
      8                   Name4                     Detail
> Current Status : Progress
      4                   Name8                     Detail
      9                   Name9                     Detail
```

By using `SortOrder="Ascending"` ,
Status will sort likes

```
Done
None
Progress
```

And by using `SortOrder="Decending"`
Status will sort likes

```
Progress
None
Done
```

But , I want to sort likes ,

```
None 
Progress
Done
```

Is there any custom sort option in `telerik RadGrid` ?

Answer (score -1):

well, you need to create an enum to do that so that:

```
None=1  Progress=2 Done=3
```

then sort by the enum value (integer)